# My custom css is not cached by wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching

I am using Wordpress with wp-super-cache but my website is still slow. Using online tool i see that the problem comme from this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="custom-css-css" type="text/css" href="http://mywebsite.com/?custom-css=1&#038;csblog=1&#038;cscache=6&#038;csrev=52" />
```

I though wp-super-cache would transform it in a real css file instead of asking database.
The version of the script dont change till 1-2 week.

And what does "cscache=6" stand for?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from Jetpack. From the Dashboard, go to Jetpack -> settings -> Custom CSS -> Configure. There you can edit the css.

Comment: I know how to edit the css, that's not the aim of my question.